# Deleting specific folders within folders that have changing names

Tags: powershell

So my boss needs me to create a script that deletes everything in a directory with the exception of the folders with the name "incoming" and "outgoing," while still deleting all files and directories within those folders. These two folders are also stored in random company name folders so I cant specify each one as the list will keep growing.

How can I delete all the incoming and outgoing folder contents without deleting the folder that those folders are stored in?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ("C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\Test") -Exclude "Incoming","Outgoing" | foreach ($_) {
    "CLEANING :" + $_.FullName
    Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force -Recurse
    "CLEANED... :" + $_.FullName
}
```

Is this the right approach? is there a switch or something that I should be adding to this command to add extra options? This script will be run daily via a Windows task I'm going to setup. Maybe there's a way to specify how deep the deletion script goes?

Comment: Tip: use the `-WhatIf` parameter with `Remove-Item`. It will show what would be deleted without actually deleting anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you need. This should delete files and folders that are in under the folders "Incoming" and "Outgoing."

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\mkrouse\Desktop\Test" -Recurse -Directory | Where-Object {($_.basename -contains "Incoming") -or ($_.BaseName  -contains "Outgoing")}
foreach($folder in $folders){
    $items = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder.FullName -Recurse
    foreach($file in $items) {
        Remove-Item -Path $file.FullName -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
    }
}
```

Comment: and this wont delete the company folders that contain the incoming and outgoing folders?

Comment: Just tested it and as i thought, it also deletes the company folders along with the incoming and outgoing folders. The company folders which would be at the path test/companyfolder and then the outgoing/incoming is test/companyfolder/outgoing, test/companyfolder/incoming. The company folders need to stay intact along with the incoming and outgoing folders, the only stuff that should get deleted are the contents of the incoming and outgoing folders.

Comment: Have you tested that? You are not using `-contains`  properly as it is an array operator. Not a string one.

Comment: @Matt I've tested it on a folder structure on my desktop and seems to work fine. PowerShell comparisons can be confusing so I never know if I should use `-contains`, `-match`, `-like`, etc..

Comment: It might work this if it treats the string as a single element array. Either way  you are using it like `-eq` so you should just use that in your example. If the op changed the string and was expecting partial matches it would not work.